# ActionScript 3 get content from file when created

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, installation, rpm

I need to make an RPM installer for my application, which runs a Java program that generates a file with some content and after the file is generated I want to pass it *only once* in my ActionScript code.

The generation of the file is fairly simple:

1. javac -classpath '.:../../lib/*' main/myProgram.java
2. java myProgram

The tricky part is here - how to pass the content of the file once it is generated to my ActionScript code? Is it possible and if yes - how can it be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you requesting this process to be run from AS3? If yes, make it sleep and periodically request an output file by path, once there's no error, there's your file.

Comment: That could work, I will try it. I guess that if there is some error (e.g. the file cannot be created) I can put a timeout and stop requesting the output, because I don't want endless requests.